Linear disjointness of normal algebraic extension
In [Tent & Ziegler] "A Course in Model Theory" section B.3, it mentions that for ring $R,S$ contained in a common field extension with a common subfield $k$, if $S$ is an algebraic normal extension of $k$, then the linear disjointness of $R,S$ over $k$ does not depend on the choice of a common extension of $R$ and $S$.
I do not understand why it ever depends on such a choice.
The definition of linear disjointness is as follows: $R$, $S$ are rings with a common subfield $k$, we say that $R$ and $S$ are linearly disjoint over $k$, if any $k$-linearly independent elements in $R$ remains $S$-linearly independent. Moreover, using the fact that the basis of $V_1\otimes_k V_2$ for $k$-vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, the $k$-basis of $V_1\otimes_k V_2$ is generated by basis of $V_1$ and $V_2$, we can deduce that $R$ and $S$ arelinearly disjoint over $k$ iff $R\otimes_k S$ is canonically isomorphic to the ring compositum of $R$ and $S$, i.e. $RS$, by $r\otimes_k s\mapsto rs$.

Your definitions are confusing. You say "$S$-linearly independent" but don't specify where, and you refer to the compositum $RS$ but don't specify where. Of course both of these definitions depend on the choice of a common overring containing $R$ and $S$ which appears nowhere in your question even though your question is precisely about it! Also I can't tell whether you require $R \cap S = k$.

@QiaochuYuan I understand now. Thanks for pointing this out.

At first I thought that the condition "$R$ and $S$ are contained in a common field extension" is redundant, but in fact $R\otimes_k S$ might not be a domain. Note that we don't assume that $R\cap S=k$. In fact, if $R,S$ are fields and $S/k$ is algebraic and Galois, then $R$ and $S$ are linearly disjoint over $k$ iff $R\cap S=k$.
Now we show the statement: linear disjointness does not depend on the choice of the common field extension for algebraic normal field extension $S/k$.
Proof. I think I have a model-theoretic proof. For $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ in $R$, any two type extensions $p_1,p_2$ of $\text{tp}(r_1,\cdots,r_n/k)$ to $k^\text{alg}$ should be $k$-conjugate, and since $S$ is invariant under the action of $\text{Aut}(k^\text{alg}/k)$, there is $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(k^\text{alg}/k)$ such that $\sigma(p_1|_S)=p_2|_S$. Then in two different common field extensions $L_1,L_2$, the type of $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ over $S$ in $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two extensions of $\text{tp}(r_1,\cdots,r_n/k)$, so they are $k$-conjugate. If $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ are $S$-linearl dependent in $L_1$, then so are they in $L_2$.
In fact, in this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8324/what-does-linearly-disjoint-mean-for-abstract-field-extensions, the author showed more: Assume that $R$ and $S$ are fields.

$R$ and $S$ are linearly disjoint over $k$ in some common field extension iff $R\otimes_k S$ is a domain.

$R$ and $S$ are linearly disjoint over $k$ in any common field extension iff $R\otimes_k S$ is a field.

If $R/k$ is algebraic or $S/k$ is algebraic, then 1. and 2. are equivalent.


Proof. For 1., linearly disjoint implies that $R\otimes_kS\to RS$ injective and $RS$ being a domain implies that $R\otimes_kS$ is a domain. Conversely, take the fraction of $R\otimes_kS$. For 2., "$\Leftarrow$" follows from the equivalent definition of linear disjointness by injectivity and the fact that a ring morphism from a field is always injective. Conversely, if $R\otimes_kS$ is not a field, then the canonical map $R\otimes_kS\to RS$ has nontrivial kernel. Assume that $S/k$ is algebraic normal. To show 1. implies 2., enough to show it when $S/k$ is finite, because linear disjointness is stable under taking union. A domain $S$ that is finite-dimensional over a field $k$ is itself a field, because the endomorphisms of $S$ induced by multiplying a nonzero element are isomorphic (trivial kernel and finite-dimensional), which means that all the nonzero elements are invertible.
